# Can i use CView-derived classes in an activex control?

Tags: mfc, activex

I have developed a MFC desktop application that views building models read from an IFC(Industrial Foundation Classes) file using DirectX to render the models in a CFormView.

Now, I want to port my application to work as a Web application using ActiveX can i achieve such thing using the same structure i used in the desktop version or do i have to consider other things ?If there other things what are they ?

In other words what kind of classes i could use in desktop application and can't use it in an ActiveX control ?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you: [Convert simple MFC CView/CDocument/CSingleDocTemplate app to ActiveX control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343473/convert-simple-mfc-cview-cdocument-csingledoctemplate-app-to-activex-control/)