# Convert simple MFC CView/CDocument/CSingleDocTemplate app to ActiveX control

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, activex

I have a fairly simple MFC app that just defines its own sub-classes of `CDocument`, `CView` and `CFrameWnd` and uses them via a `CSingleDocTemplate` to display the read-only contents of the document in a tree on the view. All very standard MFC MVC.

I now need to convert this app so that it works as an ActiveX control that I can then embed it within a larger application.

How should I go about this?

Is it possible to use the `COleControl` sub-class in place of the `CFrameWnd` sub-class in the `CSingleDocTemplate`?  Or do I need to place the `CFrameWnd` sub-class within the `COleControl` some how?

Failing that, how can I use my existing `CDocument\CView` sub-classes within an ActiveX control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Answering my own question*: I found quite a few references to an old article about this, which used to be at http://www.microsoft.com/mind/0497/mfc.asp but has long since disappeared. :(

Fortunately though, the [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/collections/web.html) still has a complete copy of it:

**["Designing ActiveX Components with the MFC Document/View Model" by Steve Zimmerman, Microsoft Interactive Developer (April 1997)](http://replay.waybackmachine.org/20070813090526/http://www.microsoft.com/mind/0497/mfc.asp)**

Steve presents source code for two new classes:

`CActiveXDocTemplate` : a sub-class of [`CSingleDocTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yha6tek%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)
`CActiveXDocControl` : a sub-class of [`COleControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77hhz71h%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

which allowed me to use my existing [`CView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezc3635w%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) and [`CDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y59b487w%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) sub-classes in an ActiveX control.

(Thanks Steve wherever you are now)